# Block Diagram Transfer Function

Tags: control-theory, signal-processing, linear-control

What is the equivalent block of the following block diagram [image]

Answer (score 0):

The figure shown is not a block diagram since there are no sum blocks to connect the outputs of the blocks. And it is not a signal-flow graph as there are blocks.

Supposing the blocks correspond to gains in a signal-flow graph, we can use [Mason's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%27s_gain_formula):

The equivalent transfer function is the ratio between the sum of the direct paths from x to y and the determinant of the loops.

Since we have two direct paths ($G(s)$ and $H(s)$) the numerator is equal to $G(s)+H(s)$, and since we have no loops, the determinant is $1$, yielding the resulting transfer function $\frac{G(s)+H(s)}{1}$.